# Assigning different numbers to variables in a term

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to create a predicate, which will generate all possible evalutions of a compound term with numbers, e.g. `assign_distinct_values([A-B], E).` should yield 99 results.

However, I can't find the nondeterminism in my current effort:

```
assign_distinct_values(E, A) :-
       term_variables(E, V),
       assign_distinct_values(E, V, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], A).

assign_distinct_values(E, [], [], E).
assign_distinct_values(E, [], _, E).
assign_distinct_values(E, V, N, A) :-
       select(Num, N, N2),
       select(Var, V, V2),
       Var is Num,
       assign_distinct_values(E, V2, N2, A).
```

which generates a symmetrical result with duplicates like:

- 1-0
- 0-1
- 0-1
- 1-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First consider using a more meaningful naming convention: I recommend appending an "s" to the names of variables that denote lists, and numbering them more systematically (starting from 0), and using a more declarative and meaningful predicate name:

```
with_distinct_integers(E0, E) :-
       term_variables(E0, Vs),
       with_distinct_integers(E0, Vs, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], E).

with_distinct_integers(E, [], [], E).
with_distinct_integers(E, [], _, E).
with_distinct_integers(E0, Vs0, Ns0, E) :-
       select(Num, Ns0, Ns),
       select(Var, Vs0, Vs),
       Var is Num,
       with_distinct_integers(E0, Vs, Ns, E).
```

Focusing on `with_distinct_integers/4` now. You see that the first clause is subsumed by the second, so you can omit the first clause without losing solutions. The variable `Var` is only used to unify it with `Num`, so you can use a single variable right away:

```
with_distinct_integers(E, [], _, E).
with_distinct_integers(E0, Vs0, Ns0, E) :-
       select(Num, Ns0, Ns),
       select(Num, Vs0, Vs),
       with_distinct_integers(E0, Vs, Ns, E).
```

You still find unintended duplicate solutions with this simplified version, and I leave it as an easy exercise to find out what causes this:

```
?- with_distinct_integers(X-Y, [X,Y], [0,1], A).
..., A = 0-1 ;
..., A = 1-0 ;
..., A = 1-0 ;
..., A = 0-1 ;
false.
```

Hint: Just reason declaratively over the simplified definition. Continuing with the simplification: Why pass around the original term when you already have everything you need, i.e., its variables, available? Consider:

```
with_distinct_integers(E) :-
       term_variables(E, Vs),
       numlist(0, 9, Ns),
       with_distinct_integers(Vs, Ns).

with_distinct_integers([], _).
with_distinct_integers([V|Vs], Ns0) :-
       select(V, Ns0, Ns),
       with_distinct_integers(Vs, Ns).
```

Example query, counting all solutions:

```
?- findall(., with_distinct_integers([X-Y]), Ls), length(Ls, L).
Ls = ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'|...],
L = 90.
```

Surprise on the side: there are only 90 solutions, not 99.

Also consider using finite domain constraints, which are relations over integers that let you easily formulate such tasks:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

with_distinct_integers(E) :-
        term_variables(E, Vs),
        Vs ins 0..9,
        all_different(Vs),
        label(Vs).
```

Example query:

```
?- with_distinct_integers(X-Y).
X = 0,
Y = 1 ;
X = 0,
Y = 2 ;
X = 0,
Y = 3 .
```

Answer (score 2):

L being the list of values and E, A the output variables

```
assign_distinct_values(E, A, L) :-
    member(E,L),
    delete(L,E,L1),
    member(A,L1).
```

using prolog predicates is quite quicker. `member(X,L)` checks if X is in L, if so, we create a new list L1 not containing X with `delete(L,X,L1)` and check again for a second member the same way.

Another version :

```
assign_distinct_values(E, A) :-
    L = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    member(E,L),
    delete(L,E,L1),
    member(A,L1).
```

Does it work ? I don't have prolog installed on my machine.

Regards

Comment: This only works for the very special case that the given term *is* a single variable. But in OP's use case, the term can actually *contain* multiple variables, corresponding for example to the query `?- assign_distinct_values(X-Y, E, [0,1]).` with your definition.